# How to delete or replace multiple line text from the text file using regex matching in C#

Tags: c#, regex, text

I have the following text file with a lot of similar text patterns (inputFile.txt):

```
 Example1 - Should be Removed (original file contains a lot of similar parts)

 Event Number (#)                

 string2

 string3

 string4


 Example2 -Should NOT be Removed

 Event Number (#)                

 string2

 string3

 string4
 string5



 Example3 - Should NOT be Removed

 Event Number (#)                
 AnyText
 string2

 string3

 string4
```

Using the following expression I am able to map necessary example (1st).
Unfortunately I have no idea how to remove this text from the text file using C#.

```
 Event number\n(^\s*$)\n(.*)\n(^\s*$)\n(.*)\n(^\s*$)\n(.*)\n(^\s*$)
```

Example of data for analyzing: 
https://gist.github.com/SeregaVRS/0d47e84607e5dc1b8e954c2c2cc50fad

You can use https://regex101.com for more details what I would like to delete using the regex

Other words I would like to clean up file remove unused examples:

**Format To Remove:**

```
 Event Number (#)                
 {Empty String}
 string2
 {Empty String}
 string3
 {Empty String} 
 string4
 {Empty String}
```

**Example that shouldn't be affected:**

```
 Event Number (#)                
 {Empty String}
 string2
 {Empty String}
 string3
 {Empty String} 
 string4
 string5
```

Most examples that I faces were related to the **single line regex matching.**

Do you have any idea how I can process with removing / replacing unused text  from the whole file using C# code?

It should be something like:

- Read input file (example below)
- **Remove / Replace text according Regex using C# - How to do this?**
- Save output (without example1)

  ```
  string regexForEmptyNotes =
      @"string\n?(.*)\n(^\s*$)\n(.*)\n(^\s*$)\n(.*)\n(^\s*$)\n(.*)\n(^\s*$)";
  var fileLines = File.ReadLines(inputFileName, Encoding.Default);
  // Something should happened in this place :) 
  Regex.Replace("Expected string as an input but not strings collection", regexForEmptyNotes, string.Empty);
  File.WriteAllLines(outputFileName, fileLines, Encoding.UTF8);
  ```

Expected outputResult.txt

```
 Example2 -Should NOT be Removed

 Event Number (#)                

  string2

  string3

  string4
  string5



  Example3 - Should NOT be Removed

 Event Number (#)                
  AnyText
  string2

  string3

  string4
```

Output file should contain only Example2 and Example3.
*Unfortunately I should save formating as is as a result it is impossible to use version with converting all text in the file to 1 long string.*

Sorry for the quite unclear explanation.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do from your question. Please read back over it and at least add an expected result.

Comment: Your example is a little unclear. It would be more helpful if you showed one code block of ***actual*** sample file contents, and then another code block with the expected results. You say you have the following text file and then show a code block that contains strings like `ExampleX` in it. Is that part of the file? What determines a section of related text? What do you mean by "unused text"?

Comment: Temporarily down-voting as "unclear", please comment back when you update and I'll remove it!

Comment: updated and added example

Comment: So the file actually contains the strings like `"Example3 - Should NOT be Removed"`? Is that what defines a region of text to compare to the others? The question is, how do you define a region of text in your file, so that they can be compared to one another. It's hard to tell if the example you're giving is the *actual text file contents* or not.

Comment: Also, to clarify, you want to remove any regions that are contained as a subset in other regions, is that correct?

Comment: added link for data that very similar as user data: https://gist.github.com/SeregaVRS/0d47e84607e5dc1b8e954c2c2cc50fad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you might do is read the whole text into a string using for example `System.IO.File.ReadAllText`. Then do the replacement and write the contents back to the same or a new file using for example `System.IO.File.WriteAllText`

If you want a match when there is no text following on the next line, you might use:

```
^[ \t]*string(?:\n[ \t]*\n.*){3}$(?!\n[ \t]*\S)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of the line
- `[ \t]*` Match 0+ times a space or tab
- `string` Match literally
- `(?:\n[ \t]*\n.*){3}$` Repeat 3 times matching a newline, optional spaces or tabs and again a newline. After that match any char 0+ times.
- `(?!\n[ \t]*\S)` Negative lookahead to assert what follows is not a newline, spaces/tabs and a non whitespace char.

For example:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllText("inputFile.txt", Encoding.Default);
var regex = new Regex(@"^[ \t]*string(?:\n[ \t]*\n.*){3}$(?!\n[ \t]*\S)", RegexOptions.Multiline);
var result = regex.Replace(lines, "");
File.WriteAllText(@"outputFile.txt", result);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have double checked you suggestion and It seems that it works for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

it's not very clear what you want do with this file. 
I'll try to answer anyway.

If you want to replace some text by identifying it you could do something like this:

example

```
Example1 - Should be Removed (original file contains a lot of similar parts)

string

string2

 string3

 string4


 Example2 -Should NOT be Removed

 string

 string2

 string3

 string4
 string5



 Example3 - Should NOT be Removed

 string
 AnyText
 string2

 string3

 string4
```

To remove Example1 by using Regex:

```
inputString = Regex.Replace(inputString , Regex.Escape("Example1"), Regex.Replace(string.Empty, "\\$[0-9]+", @"$$$0"), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. But I need to remove multiple line text - All strings from the example 1. Other words I need to remove set of strings if no any additional text below